# hwclock can't open rtc file

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to control my raspberry pi using ssh in a Windows computer DHCP.

When I try to login with root in my computer it says access denied, so I created a user and tried to login with it from my computer but it says your password has expired change password and login again.

I think it's because my hardware date is set to Jan 1970. So I tried changing the date using the date command and it only changes the system's date. Whenever I try `hwclock -w` its says `hwclock : can't open /dev/misc/rtc : no such file or directory`

I listed my /dev/ folders there is not rtc and no misc. I tried to show the logs using dmesg to figure out the file the system uses to get date in boot but I couldn't find anything.

What can I do to find out which file ?  Does anyone know why I'm getting the password expired error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raspberry is a low cost PC/iOT and does not have an RTC by default.

You either set time via NPT in an Internet connected rpi, and/or buy an RTC clock like the DS3231 that costs around 1.25€ in Aliexpress or around £9  in an uk site.

Upon connecting it to the rpi bus, you will be able to use the RTC in Linux after booting.

PS. Be sure to connect it while the rpi is off.

[image: rtc]

Comment: i'm sorry i am new to raspberry pi and linux too. so please correct me if i'm wrong i'm trying to understand. I guess this means that for me to be able to set my hardware clock to my system clock i need to have an RTC module so i guess this also means that i can not login via ssh unless i have an RTC module either that or there is another reason why i get the expired password when i try to login. do you have any idea on why i am getting the password expired message ?

Comment: ah, I got it now. You are making two questions. You should be able to login via ssh by default. Have you put an expiration date in any login?

Comment: No i did not i only thought that since i get expired password than maybe it's because my hwclock and my computer's clock have 48years of difference. so i tried the hwclock to change my hwclock and see if it works. [i dont know why i feel like i heard somewhere that default ageing for passwords in linux is 30 years ]

Comment: see this https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/setting-off-password-aging-expiration.html

Comment: i went to the shadow file and i had this for my account: 
`nada:blabla/blabla/blabla/:0:0:99999:7::: `
so i guess this means that the expiration for the password is 273 years. so i really do not understand why i'm having the password expired on the login